# CSS: Why can not use img:hover to show drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

I want to perform an action that when I hover on the image, the drop-down menu will be shown.

The below code works fine.

HTML, CSS:

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.menu:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <img src="http://sharpinsurance.ca/images/menu-collapse.png" id="menu-icon" alt="menu-icon" />
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#home">Account</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My question is why I can't use `#menu-icon:hover` to perform the action?

```
#menu-icon:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display:block;  
}
```

Comment: Do like this `#menu-icon:hover + .dropdown-menu {`

Comment: That's a descendent selector.  You have no descendants.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this structure:

```
<div class="menu">      
<img src="icon.jpg" id="menu-icon" alt="menu-icon"></img>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#home">Account</a></li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

The selector / combinator you are using is incorrect and should be:

```
#menu-icon:hover + .dropdown-menu {
display:block;  
}
```

The space between `.menu-icon` and `.dropdown-menu` you are using assumes that the menu is a child of the image **which it isn't**.

The menu is the next sibling and is selected with the `+` combinator.

[**The 30 CSS Selectors You Must Memorize**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 0):

Just like to add that using hover as the only way to show a menu is not very user-friendly. If you are not using a mouse it's not possible to interact with the menu. Also even if you are using a mouse it can be hard to interact since the menu will close as soon as the mouse is not actually hovering.

I would suggest trying something else or maybe add some JavaScript to improve the accessibility.